# generate extended public address from extended public key(xpub) for Cardano(ADA)

Tags: asp.net, .net, cryptocurrency, cardano

how can i generate extended public address from extended public key(xpub) for Cardano in .Net Core
I use CardanoSharp.wallet lib and serach in net and also use NBitcoin lib for parse XPUB but I Can not generate extended address.

please help me

Answer (score 0):

To generate extended public addresses from extended public keys (xpub) in Cardano using .NET Core and the `CardanoSharp.Wallet` and `NBitcoin` libraries:

1. Install `CardanoSharp.Wallet` and `NBitcoin` libraries.
2. Derivation path for Cardano: "m/44'/1815'/0'".
3. Generate xpub with `CardanoSharp.Wallet` from mnemonic.
4. Use `NBitcoin` to derive the address:

   - Parse xpub with `ExtKey.Parse(xpub, network)`.
   - Derive public key with the desired derivation path.
   - Get the address with `extPubKey.PubKey.GetAddress(ScriptPubKeyType.Legacy, network)`.

Comment: yes. i used these libraries but use Bech32.Encode to generate extended address